# Flutter QR Code Scanner not starting preview when view pushed [qr_code_scanner]

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera, cross-platform

Iam trying to push to the QR code scanner screen, with the following code, and when I push it I can only see a black screen (black preview), and I have to pause and start the camera manually, to actually see the camera picture (preview).

Push:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          // Material page route makes it
          builder: (context) {
            return qrScreen.QRViewApp();
          },
        ),
      );
```

The qr reader code: [I am using this example](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner/example)

And I am using the following dependency: qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2

LOG: [LOG Link (PASTEBIN)](https://pastebin.com/WEa8aFze)

Comment: please paste your logs

Comment: @griffins Pasted in the post, and heare as well: https://pastebin.com/WEa8aFze

Comment: ensure your camera is initialized before scanning qr,you can initialize it in init

Comment: @ArshneetKathuria how can I init the camera, if it is controlled by the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `qr_code_scanner` [sample](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner/example), QRViewController is paused on Android upon hot reload. See if `resumeCamera()` is ever called after the controller has been paused.

```dart
// In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
// is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
@override
void reassemble() {
  super.reassemble();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    controller!.pauseCamera();
  }
  controller!.resumeCamera();
}
```